# Html Select, Select Limit 

Tags: javascript, html

i have drop down list with multiple selection true , Now I want to limit max no of seelction to '3'.

How can I do this ?

Comment: Use JS if you want to prevent it before submitting form, otherwise you can add validation rule in your model.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9581198/jquery-limit-dropdown-check-list-selects

Comment: First of all dropDown list can be selected more than one time, Select (multiple) tag can do like that, Nothing to do with YII(even with server side), going to edit it

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge there is no way in HTML to do it, and a check in JavaScript can be quite convoluted.

Personally, I'd just validate it server-side. For example, in PHP:

```
if( count($_POST['myselect']) > 3) die("You selected too many options");
```

**EDIT:** A JavaScript solution:

```
// HTML: <select multiple data-max="3">
(function() {
    var tmp, qsa, l, i, handler, evt;
    if( document.body.attachEvent) {
        handler = "attachEvent";
        evt = "onclick";
    }
    else {
        handler = "addEventListener";
        evt = "click";
    }
    if( document.querySelectorAll) {
        qsa = document.querySelectorAll('select[multiple][data-max]');
    }
    else {
        tmp = document.getElementsByTagName('select');
        l = tmp.length;
        qsa = [];
        for( i=0; i<l; i++) {
            if( tmp[i].hasAttribute("multiple") && tmp[i].hasAttribute("data-max"))
                qsa.push(tmp[i]);
        }
    }
    l = qsa.length;
    for( i=0; i<l; i++) {
        qsa[i][handler](evt,function() {
            var opts, l, i, c, m;
            opts = this.options;
            l = opts.length;
            m = parseInt(this.getAttribute("data-max"),10);
            c = 0;
            for( i=0; i<l; i++) {
                if( opts[i].selected) c++;
                if( c > m) {
                    alert("You may only select up to "+m+" options.");
                    return false;
                }
            }
        });
    }
})();
```

I'm not 100% sure it'll work, as I haven't tested it, but it gives you an idea of how annoying a JavaScript solution would be.

Answer (score 0):

Here hs basic html and js with jquery

```
   <select name="x" id="mySelect" multiple="multiple" size="11">
        <option value="a">a</option>
        <option value="b">b</option>
        <option value="c">c</option>
        <option value="d">d</option>
        <option value="e">e</option>
        <option value="f">f</option>
        <option value="g">g</option>
        <option value="h">h</option>
        <option value="i">i</option>
        <option value="j">j</option>
        <option value="k">k</option>
    </select>

if($("#mySelect :selected").length>3){
  alert("Warning");
  return false; 
}
```